# How do you access the IAM role on a AWS Lambda function?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I am trying to use AWS Lambda and very very new to it. I implemented the HelloWorld template and everything promotes to AWS Correctly using Pycharm. Its the ARN access that is causing me problems. The sample creates a Role automatically. When I try to use it, my template.yaml doesn't use the role that was created and any one that I create doesn't seem to be accessed.

If anyone can help, that would be great.

Here is what I see on my template.yaml

```
Outputs:
# ServerlessRestApi is an implicit API created out of Events key under Serverless::Function
# Find out more about other implicit resources you can reference within SAM
# https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application- 
  model/blob/master/docs/internals/generated_resources.rst#api
ArloEventApi:
  Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Hello World function"
  Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute- 
  api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/ArloEvents/"
ArloEventFunction:
  Description: "Arlo Events Lambda Function ARN"
  Value: !GetAtt ArloEventFunctionRole.Arn
  #!GetAtt HelloWorldFunction.Arn
ArloEventFunctionIamRole:
  Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for ArloEvent function"
  Value: !GettAtt ArloEventFunctionRole.Arn
  #!GetAtt HelloWorldFunctionRole.Arn
```

This my role at AWS
[image]

Comment: Please share the tutorial that you are trying to follow

Comment: This gets autogenerated from Pycharm. It's the Helloworld Template that is generated. I don't know if it's from pycharm or a template from AWS.

Comment: can you post your template, do you mean that the role is not referred from anywhere  in the template for e.g`{ "Ref": "myrole"}`

Comment: The template is above. I did the following. I commented out the OUTPUTS section and it deployed and work. This template requires a very clear understanding if its by configuration only.